# Get error stream from IOException

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, google-geocoding-api

I am using library which issues HTTP request by calling

`java.net.URL.getInputStream()`

In the small portion of requests, it throws `IOException`. Message of this exception indicates that **HTTP Error 500** has been processed.

I am concerned if I am able to **get connection error stream from exception**. I know that 500 indicates error in the requested API, but I would like to get as many information about error as possible.

I know that

`java.net.URL.getInputStream()`

is shorthand for 
`java.net.URL.getConnection().getInputStream()`

and I could get error stream from `java.net.HttpUrlConnection` - but as library does this, it is not available for me.

The library is google [geocoder](https://code.google.com/archive/p/geocoder-java/) for java, maven artifact

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.geocoder-java</groupId>
    <artifactId>geocoder-java</artifactId>
    <version>0.16</version>
</dependency>
```

This is different from question that this question has been marked as duplicate of, as this is not about handling error from `java.net.HttpConnection` in general, but only in specific case where all I can do is only catching exception - if it is possible to obtain error stream from exception somehow.

Comment: What library are you using? We cannot help if we don't know what lib you use.

Comment: I added library to question, but I think this is more relevant to HttpUrlConnection than library itself.

Comment: @cello He is using `java.net.URL`, `java.net.HttpURLConnection`, `java.io.InputStream`, etc. All this is immediately apparent from the original question. Don't ask pointless questions here.

Comment: Hello @EJP , I think this is not duplicate question - I have edited it to give more details about what I would like to handle.

Comment: @EJP ...and this is why I thought the library is important, as the OP is restricted by the library. It was probably confusing as the OP already did an analysis of the library's source code, and there it could be solved easily, but maybe there is a way to solve it without modifying the libraries source code.